# Toggle images in a carousel in sequence with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, attr

I have the following HTML code:

```
<a class="item overlay"><img src="img/1.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img src="img/2.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img src="img/3.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img src="img/4.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img src="img/5.jpg"></a>
```

And the JS code:

```
$('.overlay > img').on('click', function(event){
var $this = $(this);
if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
  $this.attr("src","img/1-overlay.jpg").removeClass('clicked');
} else{
  $this.attr("src","img/1.jpg").addClass('clicked');
}
```

This is functional for only single image, but i want to do the same for all images in my carousel without repeat the same JS code above.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add an attribute to each image

```
<a class="item overlay"><img data-num="1" src="img/1.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img data-num="2" src="img/2.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img data-num="3" src="img/3.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img data-num="4" src="img/4.jpg"></a>
<a class="item overlay"><img data-num="5" src="img/5.jpg"></a>
```

then in the js, get the number and use it to make up the file name.

```
$('.overlay > img').on('click', function(event){
var $this = $(this);
var num = $this.attr("data-num");
if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
  $this.attr("src","img/"+num+"-overlay.jpg").removeClass('clicked');
} else{
  $this.attr("src","img/"+num+".jpg").addClass('clicked');
}
```

Comment: It works, but I have to click twice on an image to see the change, I don't know why.

Comment: Is it because they don't have the class clicked until after it's clicked?

Comment: I think so, I'll try it again. But resolve with another code - above -

Comment: I've added the "clicked" class to all images and works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to change the JS with de response of "jarchuleta", but I have to click twice on an image to see te change.

Can resolve with :

```
$('.overlay > img').on('click', function(event){
var $this = $(this);
var num = $this.attr("data-num");
var clickist = $this.attr("src");
var confirmed = "img/"+num+".jpg";
if(clickist === confirmed){
  $this.attr("src","img/"+num+"-overlay.jpg");
} else{
  $this.attr("src","img/"+num+".jpg");
}
```

It works perfectly.